# Setting Hadoop configuration property in Pig scripts

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I set some property in main function in the Hadoop configuration for running MR job like:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = new Job(conf, "BaseJob");
conf.set("schema","schema.txt");
...and more code.
```

Now instead of MR job I used Pig scripts and need to set the same property "schema" for Hadoop. I set the same property while running Pig script like `pig abc.script -param schema=schema.txt`. But that is not working.

Comment: Show us how you are using the param in your Pig script.

Comment: I am using a custom LoadFunction in Pig that using a custom record reader that is using the hadoop configuration property